# Make my UI to looks exactly the same on different resolutions

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a javascript application that runs on a Internet TV Box.

My application UI should looks exactly the same on different TV resolution (720p, 1080p, 2k, 4k etc). **my aspect ratio is 16:9**

the device that I'm developing on has **Opera 9.8** (I know, It's from stone age)

Is there any way to achieve this via pure CSS?

If not, what will be the javascript solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function that sets a font-size on the document's body:

```
var setFonts = function() {
    var size = {
        height: window.innerHeight,
        width: window.innerWidth
    };
    var ratio = size.width / size.height;
    var max = 2;
    var factor = 1.98;
    if (ratio > max) {
        size.width = size.height * factor;
    }
    size.width = parseInt(size.width);
    document.body.setAttribute('style', 'font-size:' + size.width / 26 + 'px');
    window.fontSize = size.width / 26;
};
```

After that set every dimenstion (width, height, font-size, etc) using em (not pixel or percentage).

Comment: Could you please explain your code little bit. Like what is the factor and that 26?

Comment: The 26 is the base of the px, it's by default 16, but we needed it bigger. So 1em = 26px in this case.

Comment: Also, if you want some responsiveness call this function on every window.resize.

Answer (score 0):

You can try bootstrap css with html5 if you are using

```
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
```

This line

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Automatically changes the layout of your page based on device screen size or aspect ratio.

Here is the link for learning how to use bootstrap  http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @sunny, I know bootstrap but I'm not using bootstrap because I want to keep my code as less as possible and of course use of libraries. And inital-scale does not give me what I'm looking for